# Uninstalling VS.NET 2010 Beta Breaks .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I've been running VS.NET 2010 beta for a couple of months now alongside VS.NET 2005.  As late as yesterday afternoon I was using 2005 for work.

Last night I uninstalled VS.NET 2010 and nownone of my .NET-related apps work (VS.NET 2005, SQL Server Management Studio, etc.).  The installs for these products won't work, either, nor will the 2.0 SDK or 2.0 Framework installs.

They're all failing with this error:

```
(Msgbox title) ngen.exe - Unable to Locate Component
This application has failed to start because MSVCR100.dll was not found.  Re-installing the application may fix the problem.
```

Which, of course, it doesn't, since this is the install.

Any ideas?  Google doesn't seem to have anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Solved.   The answer is...uninstall .NET Framework 4.0. The VS.NET uninstall doesn't take that with it, and apparently DOES remove the VC runtime dependency

Comment: Cheers mtutty. Note for anyone else in this situation: I got about 50 ngen.exe crashes during the uninstall of each of the .net 4 components, but after ignoring them it completed ok and everything seems to be running fine now.

Answer (score 1):

First: Never install a beta on a production machine. Use Virtual PC instead. Lesson learned.

Second: based on the dll mentioned, MSVCR100.dll, I'd say you've compiled against .NET 4.0. Recompile your programs against .NET 2.0 and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Randolpho hit the nail on the head. Never install a beta development tool on a production machine. Always use a VM or seperate box.

From the sound of it, .NET registered the new dlls for 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0. You might need a registry hack to repoint the framework to the correct location...checking and will report back.

**UPDATE**

Check the different folders for the remaining versions of .NET at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/.NETFramework/{version}/NGETService/Roots
```

and make sure there's not a lingering reference to the 4.0 dlls.

Comment: Not sure what your definition of "production" is, but I can walk away from my dev PC anytime, and be up and running on another one in a couple of hours.  In my case, the VM isn't worth the performance hit.

The actual answer is...uninstall .NET Framework 4.0.  The VS.NET uninstall doesn't take that with it, and apparently DOES remove the VC runtime dependency.